# Error overlapping layer name when loading a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have trained a composed model on keras, with one training on images using transfer learning from inception_v3 and one training on numerical feature, I had to rename the layers of the two models when creating the composed model to prevent overlapping names and it worked.

```
i=0
for layer in model.layers:
    i+=1
    layer._name = 'layer'+str(i) + str("_image")
i=0
for layer in model_structure.layers:
    i+=1
    layer._name = 'layer'+str(i) + str("_structure")
inputs1 = model.inputs
inputs2 = model_structure.inputs
outputs1 = model.layers[-2].output
outputs2 = model_structure.layers[-2].output
z = Concatenate()([outputs1,outputs2])
z = Dense(256, activation="relu")(z)
z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
outputs = Dense(NUM_CLASSES)(z)
```

The problem is that once the model is trained and saved, I can't load it because it detects two layers with the same name which shouldn't be the case :

```
combined_model = load_model('/tf/pvc_data/train_checkpoints/combined_model.h5')
ValueError: The name "tf_op_layer_" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
```

Any suggestions on how could I load the model ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to change the model names while loading the models. The following code has not been tested.

```
model_1 = keras.models.load_model('tf/pvc_data/train_checkpoints/combined_model.h5')
model_1._name = 'inceptionv3_images'
model_2 = keras.models.load_model('tf/pvc_data/train_checkpoints/combined_model.h5')
model_2._name = 'inceptionv3_numerical'

inputs1 = model.inputs
inputs2 = model_structure.inputs
outputs1 = model.layers[-2].output
outputs2 = model_structure.layers[-2].output    

merged_output = keras.layers.Add()([outputs1,outputs2])

newModel = Model(inputs=[inputs1 , inputs2], merged_output)
```

I hope it gives you a starting point to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. May be I didn't understand well the solution but my problem is with loading the combined model once trained and saved and not with the composing models